# TinyMCE configuration / init - How to prevent CDATA tags to be written?

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard CMS and the default TinyMCE HTML editor. It cleans and reformats not valid XHTML. But from some setting (tinyMCE.init?) there are CDATA tags written / added inside  tags.

In the init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
extended_valid_elements: "script[type|defer|src|language|id]"
});
```

the id is already added, this allows the id to be written inside the script tag.

```
<script type="text/html" id="custom_grid_template">
```

But after leaving the html editor, there are

```
// <![CDATA[
```

opening and closing attributes written inside the template, and knockout won't allow that.

How can I configure TinyMCE NOT to write CDATA tags?

Comment: Did you try using http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.TinyMceDeluxe ?

Comment: Hi Betrand, no, not yet, switched to  CKEditor, solved the CDATA problem. But somehow, I can't browse to my media pictures with  CKEditor. So your suggestion to go for TinyMceDeluxe is my next step. Thanks!